# Force text in a container take full width of parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, width

I'm currently trying to put up a little folio project for a college assignment, and I need it to be a minimum responsive.
The problem is, I heavily rely on a title on each page that's composed of one or more word (but only ONE line), and is surrounded by 2 horizontal borders. Theses borders must be the same width of the main, big block of content on the page. The width of this block is in % of the page to keep it responsive. Thing is, I can't seem to make the title fill all the available width: I can make its block the width it should be, responsive and all, but no matter the size of the text block, the title inside doesn't take up all the available width.

I've obviously tried the classic text-align: justify, but it doesn't work because I only have one line of text (and sometimes just one word). 
I would like my title to "stretch", like in Photoshop when you have a big block of text and tell it to be fully-justified: even if there's only one word, the text fills up the block by increasing letterspacing or word-spacing.

I can't manage to reproduce this behavior with html/css.

Any idea? I'm open to JS/Jquery solutions but as I don't really master them I didn't explore this way that much.

Here are some shots of what I'm talking about if it's too abstract:

What I want:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YspIv.jpg

What I get with text-align: justify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcIWf.jpg

I've tried several other rules, like text-justify and letterspacing, but either it doesn't change anything or it can't take dynamic values.

Thanks :)

Comment: You want the text to cover the entire width right? Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly that. I can do it manually on each title by trying and trying good values of letterspace and font-size, but I have to do it differently for each title because I don't have the same number of letters nor words and, most of all, this is not responsive because letterspace and font-size can't take % values.

Comment: I think it requeres JQuery to do.If possible i will surely create a fiddle and post it.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's what I thought. Well, thanks a lot if you can do that :)

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i am successful in creating a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/zkS8W/

Fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/zkS8W/show/

**JQuery/Javascript:**

```
var h1=$('#innerC').html();
var h2=$('#colorize').html();

var l=h2.slice(-1);

var li=h2.lastIndexOf(l);
h2=h2.substring(0,li); 

h1=h1.replace(/[ ]+/g," ");
htemp1=h1.replace(/ /g,".");

h2=h2.replace(/[ ]+/g," ");
htemp2=h2.replace(/ /g,".");

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#innerC').html(htemp1);
$('#colorize').html(htemp2);
var childW=$('#child').width();
var innerCW=$('#innerC').width()+$('#colorize').width();
var s=1;
while(innerCW<childW)
{
    $('#innerC').css({'letter-spacing':''+s+'px'});
    $('#colorize').css({'letter-spacing':''+s+'px'});
    innerCW=$('#innerC').width()+$('#colorize').width();
    s++;
}
$('#innerC').html(h1);
$('#colorize').html(h2);    
$('#colorize2').html(l);
});
```

**Note :** Add the text with normal/black color to `span with id="innerC"` .Add the text with different color to `span with id="colorize"` and change color in `.lastcolor{ color:red; }`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, that works great! Just a little problem: the last character before the end of your span, whatever it is, is always included. For example if I have as title "blabla<span class="colorizeTitle">foobar</span>" inside your spans, I will have "blablafoobar>" displayed. Know how to fix this?

Comment: If you are adding anything add it outside `<div id="child" align="center"></div>` tags . See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dHQp6/ .If this solves your problem then accept my answer.

Comment: The problem is that I need to add this class inside the title, not outside ^^' Here is what I see: http://jsfiddle.net/zkS8W/11/

Comment: I think you want the last letter to have different color?

Comment: No, just one part of the text. It depends on the title, so it's always different. To do that I usually just put the part I want to colorize inside <span class="colorize">...</span> for example but, here, the ">" of the closing tag is taken in the text.

Comment: @user3141833 i have updated my fiddle.Just add the text with different color to `span with id="colorize"` and change color in `.lastcolor{
    color:red;
}`

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot, I validate your answer :)